# Can I disable annoying heroku cli "submit user experience" prompt?

Tags: heroku, command-line-interface

Setting up a new machine, I installed latest Heroku Toolbelt.

Seems now, whensoever I run any heroku command I first get asked:

```
Would you like to submit Heroku CLI usage information to better improve the CLI
user experience?
[y/N]
```

Is there a way I can permanently disable this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Adding file `~/.heroku/config.json` with the following content worked for me on Ubuntu. Good luck!

```
{
  "skip_analytics": true
}
```